# Discrepancy between outputs from firefox and chrome for 'console.log'

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

Why would firefox give me the correct output but Chrome doesn't ?

I am trying to find the height of a div that has not been specified in the stylesheet or anywhere else.

Chrome gives me the integer value of '20', but firefox gives me the correct value (using firebug) of 516.

This is the code I am using to generate the console.log:

```
var img_h = $("#pics").height();
    console.log(img_h);

<div id="pics" width="100%">
        <img src="image1.jpg" width="45%">
        <img src="image2.jpg" width="45%">
    </div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: When do you execute the code? I know that some browsers first set the height to a initial value and the correct value is only available if the rendering and layout has taken place. So if you try to get the height to early it might be wrong.

Comment: It is at the end of my document.ready(function).

Literally right before the trailing });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want images to be loaded, instead of `document.ready` you should use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload), like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var img_h = $("#pics").height();
  console.log(img_h);
});
```

The most notable difference is that images (not created dynamically!) are loaded and ready when this code runs.

Comment: can I put this inside the 'document.ready(function){' or do I put it outside?

Comment: In case other are curious, outside is safer, @marc - Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution, but I'm leaving it up so no one else offers it either.

---

Not positive, by try wrapping the jquery in the doc ready wrapper:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    //your code
});
```

Just a theory, but it could be that the element isn't actually loaded yet when the console.log is firing.

Comment: It was in my overall document.ready(function).

There is other code in there already, so should I have two document.ready(functions) ?

Comment: Nope. That's not the issue then.